# Flutter Huawei App Linking get info from link

Tags: android, flutter, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers, appgallery-connect

i have implemented AppLinkin in my flutter app, and it works good, but i want to avoid the behaviour to open a new app instace

In android i'm using singleTask in launchMode

[image: Android Single task mode]

Also using this package [app_links](https://pub.dev/packages/app_links) to handle the link each time the user tap the link. but I only get the link, without the info, like this: https://myApp.drcn.agconnect.link/linkId

I want to know if exist a way to get the info from the link, knowing that the api is already released

Answer (score 0):

As confirmed by the team, the getAppLinking function is not supported in the singleTask launch mode. Currently, only the standard launch mode is supported.

For details, you could refer to [this Docs](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/AppGallery-connect-Guides/agc-applinking-flutter-usage-0000001063964746#section10819182720222) :

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but that is the behavior that I want to avoid

Comment: It's already on the pending list by now. The specific release time has not been determined, but the team confirms that adaptation is still underway and plans to release it with the Flutter 2.0 feature.

Comment: Thank you Shirley, that helps me a lot